# 3rd party payment provider Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, universal-analytics

A checkout flow goes like this:

- user picks a product and goes in checkout flow on mydomain.com
- user pays on otherdomain.com
- user is redirected to a thank you page on mydomain.com

The problem:
All source/channel for the conversions were marked referral from otherdomain.com

What I tried:
Adding otherdomain.com to exlused domains in Universal Analytics. Referral is gone, but now the source shows"direct/none". No new session is started each time, but I still can't connect the dots.

I'm sure this issue pops up a lot, so I'm curious how you solve it.

Bonus question: a few guides suggested we should exclude mydomain.com too. Why is that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related.

Answer (score 1):

Your domain should be excluded to avoid self-referrals, while for the payment gateway you have to put the domain in `referral exclusion` (as you did). The trick is that it becomes `direct` traffic so the previous source is attributed to the session (i.e. organic, paid, ...). However, even if the session itself is `direct`, it will be `direct`.